# Set Input Value then disable and move to next empty Input

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, input

Alright, this my be a tall order, but I am not making much headway, so I decided to ask for help.

I have a random array of names, and I would like to set these names to the HTML input, disable the HTML input with the value and move to the next one. Is that possible? and my second question is, is my randomGroup going to work, I mean, is all the 14 names be called?

all the help would be appreciated. - I am still working on it.

Here is a snippet:

```js
var randomGroup = ["Luciano", "Patrick", "SHL", "Leo", "Marilyn", "Ranbir", "Helena", "Annie", "Saikaran", "Julie", "Albert" , "Chris", "Igor", "Staci"]

Array.prototype.randomElement = function(){
 return this[Math.floor(Math.random() * this.length)]
}

var myRandomElement = randomGroup.randomElement();
/*console.log(myRandomElement);*/

function appendItem(){
  var inputs = document.getElementByTagName('input').value = '';
  var setInputs = document.getElementByTagName('input').innerHTML = myRandomElement;
 /* myRandomElement = randomGroup.randomElement();*/
    if (inputs == 0) {
    inputs = setInputs;
  } 
}

appendItem();
```

```css
body{
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: -10px;
}

#group1, #group2, #group3, #group4, #group5, #group6, #group7 {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p id="group1">Group 1</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div> 
<div>
  <p id="group2">Group 2</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <p id="group3">Group 3</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <p id="group4">Group 4</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <p id="group5">Group 5</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <p id="group6">Group 6</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
  <p id="group7">Group 7</p>
  <input type="text" />
  <input type="text" />
</div>
```

Comment: sorry forgot to add the pen http://codepen.io/lucky500/pen/NGPbax

Answer (score 3):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve but here are some pointers:

1. There is no such function as `getElementByTagName`, it should be `getElementsByTagName`
2. `getElementsByTagName` returns a [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). To access an element in this list you could do `document.getElementsByTagName('input')[0]`. This would get the first input.
3. This does absolutely nothing: `if (inputs == 0) { inputs = setInputs; }`

Answer (score 1):

Your Mistakes

1.`getElementsByTagName` is correct . `getElementByTagName`  doesn't exist.
2.When you get a array of elements you have to loop them to process.
3.To insert a value into a input feild you have to use `value` not `innerHTML`

FIX:(Only `appenItem` function has issue)

PURE JS Version [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/SantoshPandu/84zzr66u/)

Note:jQuery version is commented in this fiddle

```
function appendItem() {
    var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        inputs[i].value = myRandomElement
    }
}
```

jQuery Version

```
function appendItem() {
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
$('input[type=text]').each(function (index, Obj) {
        $(this).val(myRandomElement)
})   
}
```

Comment: Thanks Santosh. That at least help me with direction.

Comment: glad to help :) and one suggestion whenever your JS doesn't work just open the browser console and see the error.

Comment: and if you want to use all names in array use `inputs[i].value = randomGroup[i]` but remember number of names in array must be  >= number of input elements